# How to get the fewest bytes required to store an integer value with macro?

Tags: c, macros

For example,if the integer is less than 255,than it can be restored in **1** byte,

if it's greater than 255,it requires at lest **2** bytes.

How to write such a `BYTES_REQUIRED(i)` macro?

Comment: Why a macro? Do you know how to do it with a normal function?

Comment: @Mat ,in fact I can only think of this one: `if(i<255)return 1;else if(i>255 && i < 2^16)return 2;...`,which is too long to be a macro.

Comment: Why do you need a macro?

Comment: @Mat ,in my case, the `i` are all constants, I want a macro so that the result can be calculated at compile time,no run time overhead.

Comment: And what is the range of your `i`s? 32bit? 64bit? More?

Comment: @new_perl any optimizing compiler will inline (and evaluate to a costant) such small *functions* at compile-time; there's no need for a macro...

Comment: Use `?:` and it can fit into a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a C99 compiler make the cast below to `(unsigned long long)`.
Also you can (and should) extend the construct to 8 or 16 bytes (that's left as an exercise)

```
#include <limits.h>

#define BYTES_REQUIRED(i)                            \
           !((unsigned long)(i) >>     CHAR_BIT) ? 1 \
         : !((unsigned long)(i) >> 2 * CHAR_BIT) ? 2 \
         : !((unsigned long)(i) >> 3 * CHAR_BIT) ? 3 \
         :                                         4
```

Comment: Why do I need to cast it to unsigned long long if it's c99 compiler?

Comment: Because `unsigned long long` was not recognized by C89 and it is at least as large as `unsigned long`. Using `unsigned long long` doesn't lose anything (except C89 compatability) and possibly gains a wider range of working values.

Answer (score 0):

This uses an efficient divide and conquer approach:

```
#define BYTES_REQUIRED(i) (((i) & 0xFFFF0000) ? (((i) & 0xFF000000) ? 4 : 3) : (((i) & 0xFF00) ? 2 : 1))
```

If you don't mind eliminating the odd case of 3 bytes, which has no primitive type that matches it, do:

```
#define BYTES_REQUIRED(i) (((i) & 0xFFFF0000) ? 4 : (((i) & 0xFF00) ? 2 : 1))
```

Be warned neither one of these handles negative numbers, since it sees the sign extended 1 bits as used space. This requires another conditional to account for (e.g. if negative, negate).

Answer (score 0):

You effectively need to calculate log2(i). There's no trivial way of doing that portably, quickly, for the maximum integer value supported by the compiler and with a macro.

Options:

1.Calculate the logarithm in a loop:

```
// 64+-bit version:
unsigned long BYTES_REQUIRED(unsigned long long i)
{
  unsigned long bits = 0;
  while (i)
  {
    i >>= 1;
    bits++;
  }
  if (bits == 0) bits = 1;
  return (bits + 7) / 8; // we're assuming that byte=8 bits, but CHAR_BIT may be > 8
}
```

2.Use an intrinsic function (effectively, a dedicated CPU instruction) of the compiler, if available. For MSVC++:

```
// 64-bit version, not available for 32-bit code:
unsigned long BYTES_REQUIRED(unsigned long long i)
{
  unsigned long index;
  if (_BitScanReverse64(&index, i) == 0)
  {
    index = 1;
  }
  return (index + 8) / 8;
}

// 32-bit version, available for 32 and 64-bit code:
unsigned long BYTES_REQUIRED(unsigned long i)
{
  unsigned long index;
  if (_BitScanReverse(&index, i) == 0)
  {
    index = 1;
  }
  return (index + 8) / 8;
}

// 64-bit version available for 32 and 64-bit code:
unsigned long BYTES_REQUIRED(unsigned long long i)
{
  unsigned long index;
  if (_BitScanReverse(&index, (unsigned long)(i >> 32)))
  {
    index += 32;
  }
  else if (_BitScanReverse(&index, (unsigned long)i) == 0)
  {
    index = 1;
  }
  return (index + 8) / 8;
}
```

3.Use `if` or `?:` knowing the size of the biggest supported integer type... Others have described this method already.

Comment: Solving log-base-2 gives accuracy to the bit, which is not needed. You are solving a harder problem then he asked, then dividing away the extra precision. _BitScanReverse might make some sense as it is fast on some processors, but he asked for something that resolves at compile time, so the performance is irrelevant anyway. The instrinsic makes the code less portable and in exchange for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you asked for a C macro, because this C++ templated function could have been helpful (it should work for any integer type supported by your compiler).

```
template <typename T> int bytesRequired(T value) {
  boost::function_requires< boost::IntegerConcept<T> >();
  for (int i=0; i<=sizeof(T); i++, value/=256)
    if (value == 0) return i;
}
```

Another approach that should be faster (because it's branchless), if you don't just need compile-time evaluation, is the bitscan that was mentioned by Alex.